# Decompile Java Application packed with launch4j

Tags: java, class, decompiler, launch4j

I have a Java application that was converted to an .exe with launch4j. For several reasons I need to get access to the class files of the application.

The first thing I tried was unpacking the exe with 7zip. That way I get a handful of class files, but definately not the whole application packed in the exe (the class files seem to belong to launch4j).

What other options are there?

Comment: They may have used this to obfuscate and protect the code as well.  Can I ask why you need to modify and decompile this executable?  Can you not ask the vendor of the application for the source code?

Comment: Since I'm the vendor that would not help ;-)  I've created the application some time ago. I thought I wouldn't have to touch the application ever again, so now all my projects files are gone. Only the executable remains. And no, the sources weren't obfuscated or anything...

Comment: When you create a launch4j exe that wraps a JAR, the resulting `.exe` file is actually still a valid JAR due to the way the ZIP file format allows arbitrary "junk" to be prepended to a ZIP file.  Launch4J doesn't itself do any kind of obfuscation, it simply sticks an executable header on the front of whatever JAR you told it to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to extract the JAR from the Launch4j executable:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html

Typically the executable packages necessary JAR's as executable resources and then looks for a JDK on the path to execute.

Once you get the JAR file you should be able to decompile it.

Answer (score -4):

You cannot get access to class files. Exes are created, So that nobody can get access to your code.
If somehow , you are able to get access to jar files then you can decompile them to get the code and make changes.

Comment: Actually, the point of launch4j is to provide a better experience for the user, not to protect the jar file. The same way UPX is so easy to unpack because it’s a packer, not a protector.